# In STP, how does a switch know that a peer port is blocked?

Tags: spanning-tree

Let's consider the below image:

[image]

Let's assume the following:

1. Cat1 is the root bridge
2. fa0/23 on cat2 is blocked after stp has converged

When a frame arrives at cat1 to be forwarded to cat2, how does Cat1 determine not to send the traffic via fa0/23, since as far as Cat1 is concerned, fa0/23 on cat1 is not blocked?

Comment: Has any answer solved your question? Then please accept it or your question will keep popping up here forever. Please also consider voting for useful answers.

Answer (score 2):

Usually the lower port ID (for same link metric) takes precedence, so most likely Fa0/24 would be blocked.

The algorithm runs like that: Cat2 recognizes Cat1 as root bridge on Fa0/23 and Fa0/24. It selects Fa0/23 as root port for lower port ID.

Accordingly, Fa0/23 on Cat1 becomes a designated port. Fa0/24 is neither root nor designated port, so it is blocked.

Actual frame forwarding is based on the switch's MAC address table. When Cat2 uses only Fa0/23 for sending frames towards Cat1, Cat1's MAC table shows all addresses only on Fa0/23, so that is used to forward frames to end nodes.

Comment: Thanks @Zac67. When Cat1's MAC address table is empty, will the traffic from CAT1 towards CAT2 be flooded on both ports, even though one of the ports on CAT2 is blocked?

Comment: No forwarding is done when a port is blocked, neither unicast nor broadcast nor flooding.

Comment: Hi @Zac67. I am talking about the scenario where mac tables of both switches are empty. Let's take your comment as example where fa0/24 on cat2 is blocked after stp convergence. When an external traffic arrives on cat1, cat1 won't have any clue that fa0/24 on cat2 is blocked, right? Will it flood both the ports and the traffic would be dropped once it reaches cat2's fa0/24?

Comment: Once a port is blocked, its MAC table entries are removed and stay removed.